# Como configurar NSPredicate para realizar filtro?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, filtro, nspredicate

Estou implementando um filtro, onde preciso fazer a busca dos registros no Core Data, que tenham "sim" em determinadas colunas.

Tabela:

[image: Tabela exemplo]

Por exemplo, retornar os elementos que tenham sim nas colunas ATRIBUTO1, ATRIBUTO3 e ATRIBUTO 5

Neste exemplo retornaria os registros:

```
linha1 e linha3.
```

Tentei usar a seguinte configuração com NSPredicate:

```
NSPredicate* argumentosBusca = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"atributo1 == %@&&atributo2 == %@&&atributo3 == %@&&atributo4 == %@&&atributo5 == %@",[arrayEscolhas objectAtIndex:0],[arrayEscolhas objectAtIndex:1],[arrayEscolhas objectAtIndex:2],[arrayEscolhas objectAtIndex:3],[arrayEscolhas objectAtIndex:4] ];
```

Mas deste modo so permite retornar os registros quando todas as colunas estão idênticas a configuração do `NSPredicate`.

Comment: Acho que não compreendi direito. Primeiro você disse pra buscar os argumentos que combinem com `sim, nao, sim, nao e sim`, e é só a **linha1** que está assim. Mas por outro lado você disse que precisa de resultados com valor "sim".

Comment: Perdão. Eu vou reformular. Eu dei uma olhada, revisei algumas vezes mas ainda assim não ficou claro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso você precisa de um **OR** e não **AND** em suas condições. Seu *predicate* teria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
atributo1 == 'sim' || atributo3 == 'sim' || atributo5 == 'sim'
```

Pois neste caso, pode haver **sim** em qualquer uma das três colunas e não exatamente nas três, o que irá te retornar as linhas 1 e 3, como você citou.

Comment: Eu fiz um teste com `||` mas vou verificar novamente, pois vi um erro na busca. Vou ver como fica novamente.

Comment: Funcionou, o problema foi que eu mudei o conteúdo do banco, e fiz a verificação errada. Agora está ok!!

Comment: Uma outra observação, eu também troquei o `"não"` com um `x` na strings que configura a busca para que a comparação com `"nao"` não fosse realizada. Deste modo so a comparação com o sim seria considerada.